# DIV covering the whole page (IE7)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

What I am trying to achieve is to tell users that are using older IE version that they will not be able to view the website correctly as the IE does not support many modern techniques.
I could use and alert popup of courser, but would like to have a layer opening over the whole page instead.

I have tried to achieve this with a fixed div but it didn't work. IE simply shows the div on the top of the page instead of covering the page from side to side.

here is my CSS

```
background-color: #c0c0c0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:100;
```

I read in other posts that the problem might be in placing the div inside the body... So I move it outside, but the result was the same.

This is the piece of code I am using

```
<?

 $ie6 = "MSIE 6.0";  
 $ie7 = "MSIE 7.0"; 
 $ie8 = "MSIE 8.0"; 
 $ie9 = "MSIE 9.0"; 

 $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];  

 $browser = substr("$browser", 25, 8);  

 if($browser == $ie6 || $browser == $ie7 || $browser == $ie8 || $browser == $ie9){ 

//echo "<script>alert('Your Browser is Internet Explorer version $browser. Please update your browser to Internet Explorer version 10 to view the website correctly. IE versions under 10 does not support many of the modern web technologies and therefore you will not see the website correctly. You can also use other browsers like Chrome, Mozila, Opera, etc');</script>";
print "<div class=ie><div class=ie_message>Your Browser is Internet Explorer version $browser. Please update your browser to Internet Explorer version 10 to view the website correctly. IE versions under 10 does not support many of the modern web technologies and therefore you will not see the website correctly. You can also use other browsers like Chrome, Mozila, Opera, etc</div></div>"; 
}  
?>
```

Cannot provide link as I am testing if on my server locally

Thanks

Comment: some more code?? link???

Comment: So width appears at 100%, but height doesn't stretch? Silly idea: maybe you could try `bottom: 0; height:9999px` while removing `top:0`.

Comment: Not an answer, but I would say show a simple div at the top of the page, not a div that obscures the entire page (Like the div you see on StackOverflow if you visit it with Javascript disabled). After all, many people use IE7 not out of choice but because they have no choice (eg government dept, etc.). IMO, Showing a div covering the page is like showing a popup ad (I leave such sites instantly, never to go back)

Comment: just edited the original post with a bit more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some browsers does not support `fixed` postion, please try with `absolute` position:

```
background-color: #c0c0c0;
position:absolute; /* <-- absolute position */
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:100;
```

Comment: @largan i think the problem is not because of CSS style of div, you should looking for somewhere else in your code

Comment: @largan put the div class in quotation:  `"<div class='ie'><div class='ie_message'>`

Comment: it worked already... the problem was that i use 'ie' in the css instead of 'div.ie'

Answer (score 0):

I think IE (and other browsers) come with a default margin setting. Inputting `body {margin: 0;}` might help.

Edit: Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but if you use percentages, it's not 100% of the entire page, but rather 100% of its parent element, which is the body. Therefore, if the body has margins on it, the overlaying div cannot expand past those margins.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with this,

```
div.ie {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    z-index:100;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/AeuxM/show/ on IE

Comment: what are you getting exactly ? Means can you check whats the parent element of div.ie ?